# X-CUBE-CELLULAR : number of uart requested to work with LwIP + CS

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

Do LwIP and CS (Cellular Service) of X-CUBE-CELLULAR need 2 uart to work (one for each service) ? Or they need just one uart?
If just one uart is needed, how is it shared between them?
[image]

Comment: Lwip and CS does not require any UARTS. The hardware can be connected by the UART, USB, SPI, I2C, MII etc

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you: X-CUBE-CELLULAR supports several hardware interfaces.
Indeed, as you've written, LwIP speaks with UART not directly, but with the following:
LwIP -> PPPoSIF -> IPC -> UART0
Same for CS:
CS -> AT -> IPC -> UART1
Can UART0 and UART1 be the same UART ?

Comment: Why not? Of course it can be the same uart